# .htaccess rewrite foo.com/account to my.foo.com URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the URL example.com/account to my.example.com and if my.example.com is loaded it will show content from example.com/account while keeping the user at my.example.com

Comment: What folder is the sub domain (my.example.com) pointing to?

Comment: The root of the site.

Comment: I have done some research and the key here is that I'm not redirecting, I'm rewriting. Maybe mod_proxy is something I should look into?

Comment: If both domains are on same host then you don't need mod - proxy.  I have posted a `mod-rewrite` based solution bellow.

Comment: One thing I failed to mention is that the urls are dynamically generated. I can't just call on /account in the htaccess file since php is creating the urls dynamically. The directory does not exist, it's dynamic.

Comment: Can you clarify **php is creating the urls dynamically** with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in htaccess in your root

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /account  [L]
```